# How to add a file field in single product details page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, woocommerce

I am developing a print shop kind of website. I want my users to get an option to upload their design samples before they add to cart.

I found a couple of plugins but I am not pretty sure  if there is any code snippet or plugin available to do this.

However I am able to create a text field but I am not sure how do I manage a file input field.

Comment: You can add custom fields using "Advanced Custom Fields" Plugin for any post type.

Comment: [Product Addons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons) does exactly that.